# SSL Cipher Suite Order GPO

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, windows-registry

Thanks in advance for reading. I'm using Win Server 2012 R2 to dish out group policies.

I've created a GPO to define the SSL Cipher Suite Order under **Policies > Admin Templates > Network > SSL Confugration Settings** and have set it to **"Enabled"**.

I'm using a list of strong cipher suites from Steve Gibsons website found [here](https://www.grc.com/miscfiles/SChannel_Cipher_Suites.txt).

I've put them all on 1 long line as it states to do.

I've also manipulated a default registry value located at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Cryptography\Configuration\Local\Default\00010002
```

These are the same values I'm using from Gibsons site - on separate lines with no commas

My registry values change but I **cannot** get the SSL Configuration settings to display **"Enabled"**

Does anyone have insight on how to correct this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the SSL Cipher suites box does not exceed more than 1023 characters.